# How reload system ENV in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, environment-variables, rubymine

I try to set `ENV` variable in `~/.bash_profile`, for example `export foo='42'`.
If RubyMine was running, I can't read this `foo` variable as `ENV['foo']`.
If I restart RubyMine, I can read `foo` from system ENV.
How can I say RubyMine, that it must to reload system ENV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Environment variables are inherited by newly started subprocesses. After the subprocess has started, it has its own independent set of environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it.